# ScreenPointToRay, What's behind the function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lua, roblox

I'd like to know what code is behind Camera:ScreenPointToRay may it be Unity or ROBLOX.

My situation is that I have a position in WorldSpace and the camera's ViewportSize,
I'd like to have a function that does ScreenPointToRay,
I'm assuming you'd only need those two parameters to create this function but I have no clue how.

May someone spoon-feed me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this calculation. This version will only work for perspective cameras, but can be modified to work on orthographic cameras as well. Unfortunately I an unable to share code, but I will try to explain as best I can.

1. From your camera, you will need to generate a Matrix4x4 by inverting the result of multiplying the Camera.projectionMatrix by the Camera.worldToCameraMatrix.
2. You will need to convert your screen space pixel into a clip plane coordinate. In the clip plane -1,-1 is equivalent to 0,0, and 1,1 is equivalent to Camera.pixelWidth, Camera.pixelHeight.
3. Next you will use the Matrix4x4.MultiplyPoint function to multiply your clip point.
4. The direction of your ray is the result from step 3 minus the camera's position.
5. Construct the ray using the direction from step 4 and use the camera's position as the ray origin.

If you are trying to do this outside of the Unity API, the Matrix4x4.MultiplyPoint function will need to created as well.

Answer (score 0):

The [Roblox API](http://robloxdev.com/api-reference) has a section on the function you're looking for: [ScreenPointToRay](https://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Camera/ScreenPointToRay).

The [Unity Scripting Reference](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/) also has a section their own [ScreenPointToRay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html) function.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this article](http://blog.three-eyed-games.com/2018/05/03/gpu-ray-tracing-in-unity-part-1/), it goes through using the matrices available on the Camera of Unity to create rays for all pixles inside a compute shader